# Windows firewall blocks remote desktop with custom port

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, remote-desktop, firewall

I was able to use my remote desktop with custom port when I was using Kaspersky Internet Security. Now, I have uninstalled my Kaspersky and switch to Avast!. Therefore, the windows firewall is turned on back again. However, after the firewall is turned on, I cannot connect to the remote desktop. I have set the remote desktop "checked" in the windows firewall as shown by here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-my/windows7/use-remote-desktop-when-windows-firewall-is-on.

So, I am guessing it is caused by the custom port setting of my remote desktop. So, how can I unblock that on firewall to make my remote desktop works again?

Thank you.

Comment: You are essentially asking how do you add a port to the windows firewall. (which would be windows firewall behaving as one would want from a firewall!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To open custom port in Windows Firewall, you can do the following:

> 1. In your **Windows Firewall** in Control Panel, click on the
>      **Advanced Settings** option on the left.
> 2. In the **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security** window that
>      opens, click on the **Inbound Rules** on the left.
> 3. Click on the **New Rule** on the right side of the window.
> 4. Select **Port** on the list of options.
> 5. Select **TCP** (or **UDP** if that is what you require) and **Specific local ports**, and then write your
>      ports in the text box to the right of **Specific local ports** (i.e.
>      1234).
> 6. Select **Allow the connection** in the next window.
> 7. Select the options which you need from **Domain, Private, Public**
>      (private and public are the network types that you select when you
>      connect to the new network, and windows asks you to select the
>      network type, and domain is obviously your domain).
> 8. Finally, write a **Name** and **Description** in the window that
>      shows next.  Click **FINISH**.

Your port should be now allowed through the Windows Firewall.

Comment: I would like to highlight step #2-#8!!!! I have spent hours after having opened ports through my home router, only to get confused about why none of my other Windows PC with customized ports should be inaccessible for RDP without having disabled the firewall completely.

Comment: If you want to limit the port to RDP access, you should specify "Remote Desktop Services" under Programs&Services->Services.

Answer (score 2):

If you changed the RDP listening port you will need to create a **custom** Windows firewall rule to listen on that port.

**Create a firewall rule for new port:**

- Open *Windows Firewall with Advanced Security*

  1. Create a new rule
  2. Select "Inbound Rules" on the top left
  3. Right-click and select "New Rule…"
  4. A new "Inbound Rule Wizard" window opens
  5. Select "Program"
  6. click Next
  7. Select “This program path:”
  8. Type **System** in the text field
  9. Click Next
  10. Select “Allow the connection”
  11. Click Next
  12. Choose the profiles that the rule is for
  13. Click Next
  14. Name the new rule
  15. I would use something like “RDP3390” or whatever the new port number is
  16. Click "Finish"
  17. Test your port by going to [www.whatsmyip.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/) and use their port scanner. You should be able to turn the rule off and off the scan fail.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the previous answers I must add the following:

In case that you want to connect to a Virtualbox machine through a RDP custom port
you have to disabled the "Virtual Box Manager" default rule, who is blocking all the connection to the Virtual Box Software, without this, the inbound rules that you add  will not work.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is still having difficulty with this, this is what I had to do...

Windows 10 creates 3 inbound firewall rules when you set options for remote desktop.
You need to create 3 new rules exactly like those 3 rules except you must specify your new custom port instead.

The 3 rules are:

Remote Desktop - Shadow (TCP-In)

Remote Desktop - User Mode (TCP-In)

Remote Desktop - User Mode (UDP-In)

you cannot copy and paste them so you must read them and then create from scratch as program rules in Inbound rules and edit accordingly.

Then when you have done that you must disable the above 3 microsoft rules which point to port 3389.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @percept, would you mind mentioning where to view and create the rules?